# Portable emulation of flexible array member in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).

What I have:

```
template<typename T>
struct SkipListNode
{
    T data;
    SkipListNode* next[32];
};
```

The problem with this code is that it wastes space - it requires all nodes to contain 32 pointers. Especially considering that in typical list, half of the nodes will only need one pointer.

The C language has a neat feature called flexible array member that could solve that problem. Had it existed in C++ (even for trivial classes), I could write code like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct SkipListNode
{
    alignas(T) char buffer[sizeof(T)];
    SkipListNode* next[];
};
```

and then manually create nodes with a factory function and destroying them when deleting elements.

Which brings the question - how can I emulate such functionality *portably*, without undefined behaviour in C++?

I considered `malloc`ing the buffer and then manipulating the offsets appropriately by hand - but it's too easy to violate the alignment requirements - if you `malloc(sizeof(char) + sizeof(void*)*5)`, the pointers are unaligned. Also, I'm not even sure if such hand-created buffers are portable to C++.

Note that I don't require the exact syntax, or even ease of use - this is a node class, internal to the skip list class, which won't be a part of the interface at all.

Comment: Have you tried a vector? `std::vector<SkipListNode*> next`

Comment: @NathanOliver A vector could work. But you can assume more about the array of pointers - that the size and capacity of the array won't change during the entire lifetime of the node. Also, I don't need to store the size together with the array. ...or should I just give up on this idea?

Comment: A `std::array<SkipListNode*>` has fixed size and capacity.

Comment: You fixed size skip list is nice, if it covers the maximum amount of data stored. It does not have an additional indirection introduced to variable sized node. However, if the amount of data is tiny, it is a waste of storage. You may use a template.

Comment: @MattG Which has the same problem as the first approach.

Comment: @DieterLücking So you're suggesting I should parametrize the height of the nodes in the skip list class? Or to just make skip list node a template?

Comment: @milleniumbug Maybe `template<typename T, unsigned Size> struct SkipListNode`

Comment: `malloc` is guaranteed to return a pointer suitably aligned for any object (that's not "overaligned"). So is `operator new()`. A common approach is to define your class as `struct SkipListNode { T data; SkipListNode* next[1]; };` then allocate `offsetof(SkipListNode, next) + N*sizeof(SkipListNode*)` bytes, then use placement new to construct a `SkipListNode` instance in this buffer. `offsetof` trick accounts for any padding between `data` and `next`.

Comment: `I don't need to store the size together with the array` How else would you know how much memory you have allocated, how many elements in the `next` array you can access without buffer overrun?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik AFAIK this approach isn't strictly portable when I'm accessing through the array (the compiler can assume the `n` in `ptr->array[n]` must be 0) - that's why flexible array member got introduced in C99. But I think I know how can I get around it - I use this approach to figure out the space of the object, do offsetof to figure out the position of the array, and then do pointer arithmetic on the buffer as if wasn't typed at all. I'll post an self-answer later.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I don't need to know the size because a.) `free` doesn't need to know the size, and b.) thanks to how skip list works, when I access the node through a pointer on level N, I can assume the node has at least N nodes. Therefore I don't need to know the size unless I'm missing something fundamental about how skip list works.

Comment: @DieterLücking Your approach seems promising. Yet I can't see how can I manipulate the nodes, unless every node in the list has the same size. Can you elaborate?

Comment: `the compiler can assume the n in ptr->array[n] must be 0` Such a compiler would be non-conforming. The standard allows "flat addressing" of arrays allocated next to each other. "**3.9.2/3** If an object of type `T` is located at an address `A`, a pointer of type `cv T*` whose value is the address `A` is said to point to that object, **regardless of how the value was obtained**. [ Note: For instance, the address one past the end of an array (5.7) would be considered to point to an unrelated object of the array’s element type that might be located at that address... —end note ]"(emphasis mine.)

Comment: Combine this with "**3.8/1** The lifetime of an object of type `T` begins when ... storage with the proper alignment and size for type `T` is obtained..." to convince yourself that there's a valid array of `SkipListNode*` of length `N`, addressable via `next` pointer, once the allocation is performed the way I've shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75522/discussion-between-milleniumbug-and-igor-tandetnik).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the implementation I wrote, [based on R. Martinho Fernandes's idea](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22755998#22755998) - it constructs a buffer that happens to have a correct size and alignment in specific places (the `AlignmentExtractor` is used extract the offset of the pointer array, which ensures that the pointers in the buffer have correct alignment). Then, placement-new is used to construct the type in the buffer.

`T` isn't used directly in `AlignmentExtractor` because `offsetof` requires standard layout type.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct ErasedNodePointer
{
    void* ptr;
};

void* allocate(std::size_t size)
{
    return ::operator new(size);
}

void deallocate(void* ptr)
{
    return ::operator delete(ptr);
}

template<typename T>
struct AlignmentExtractor
{
    static_assert(alignof(T) <= alignof(std::max_align_t), "extended alignment types not supported");
    alignas(T) char data[sizeof(T)];
    ErasedNodePointer<T> next[1];
};

template<typename T>
T& get_data(ErasedNodePointer<T> node)
{
    return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(node.ptr);
}

template<typename T>
void destroy_node(ErasedNodePointer<T> node)
{
    get_data(node).~T();
    deallocate(node.ptr);
}

template<typename T>
ErasedNodePointer<T>& get_pointer(ErasedNodePointer<T> node, int pos)
{
    auto next = reinterpret_cast<ErasedNodePointer<T>*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(node.ptr) + offsetof(AlignmentExtractor<T>, next));
    next += pos;
    return *next;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
ErasedNodePointer<T> create_node(std::size_t height, Args&& ...args)
{
    ErasedNodePointer<T> p = { nullptr };
    try
    {
        p.ptr = allocate(sizeof(AlignmentExtractor<T>) + sizeof(ErasedNodePointer<T>)*(height-1));
        ::new (p.ptr) T(std::forward<T>(args)...);
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < height; ++i)
            get_pointer(p, i).ptr = nullptr;
        return p;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        deallocate(p.ptr);
        throw;
    }
}

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    auto p = create_node<std::string>(5, "Hello world");
    auto q = create_node<std::string>(2, "A");
    auto r = create_node<std::string>(2, "B");
    auto s = create_node<std::string>(1, "C");

    get_pointer(p, 0) = q;
    get_pointer(p, 1) = r;
    get_pointer(r, 0) = s;

    std::cout << get_data(p) << "\n";
    std::cout << get_data(get_pointer(p, 0)) << "\n";
    std::cout << get_data(get_pointer(p, 1)) << "\n";
    std::cout << get_data(get_pointer(get_pointer(p, 1), 0)) << "\n";

    destroy_node(s);
    destroy_node(r);
    destroy_node(q);
    destroy_node(p);
}
```

Output:

```
Hello world
A
B
C
```

Longer explanation:

The point of this code is to create a node dynamically, without using types directly (type erasure). This node stores an object, and `N` pointers, with `N` variable at runtime.

You can use any memory as if it had a specific type, provided that:

1. size is correct
2. alignment is correct
3. (only non-triviably constructible types) you manually call the constructor before using
4. (only non-triviably destructible types) you manually call the destructor after using

In fact, you rely on this every time you call `malloc`:

```
// 1. Allocating a block
int* p = (int*)malloc(5 * sizeof *p);
p[2] = 42;
free(p);
```

Here, we treat the chunk of memory returned by `malloc` as if it was an array of ints. This must work because of these guarantees:

- `malloc` returns a pointer guaranteed to be properly aligned for any object type.
- If your pointer `p` points to aligned memory, `(int*)((char*)p + sizeof(int))` (or `p + 1`, which is equivalent) also does.

The dynamically created node must have enough size to contain `N` `ErasedNodePointer`s (which are used as handles here) and one object of size `T`. This is satisfied by allocating enough memory in `create_node` function - it will allocate `sizeof(T) + sizeof(ErasedNodePointer<T>)*N` bytes or more, *but not less*.

That was the first step. The second is now we extract the required position relative to the beginning of a block. That's where `AlignmentExtractor<T>` comes in.

`AlignmentExtractor<T>` is a dummy struct I use to ensure correct alignment:

```
// 2. Finding position
AlignmentExtractor<T>* p = (AlignmentExtractor<T>*)malloc(sizeof *p);
p->next[0].ptr = nullptr;
// or
void* q = (char*)p + offsetof(AlignmentExtractor<T>, next);
(ErasedTypePointer<T>*)q->ptr = nullptr;
```

It doesn't matter how I got the position of the pointer, as long as I obey the rules of pointer arithmetic.

The assumptions here are:

- I can cast any pointer to `void*` and back.
- I can cast any pointer to `char*` and back.
- I can operate on a struct as if it was a char array of size equal to the size of the struct.
- I can use pointer arithmetic to point at any element of an array.

These all are guaranteed by C++ standard.

Now, after I have allocated the block of enough size, I calculate the offset with `offsetof(AlignmentExtractor<T>, next)` and add it to the pointer pointing to the block. We "pretend" (the same way the code "1. Allocating a block" pretends it has an array of ints) the result pointer points to beginning of the array. This pointer is aligned correctly, because otherwise the code "2. Finding position" couldn't access the `next` array due to misaligned access.

If you have a struct of standard layout type, the pointer to the struct has the same address as the first member of the struct. `AlignmentExtractor<T>` is standard layout.

That's not all though - requirements 1. and 2. are satisfied, but we need to satisfy requirements 3. and 4. - the data in the node doesn't have to be trivially constructible or destructible. That's why we use placement-new to construct the data - the `create_node` uses variadic templates and perfect forwarding to forward arguments to the constructor. And the data is destroyed in the `destroy_node` function by calling the destructor.

Comment: @Brian Sure. I posted more detailed explanation. I described what I think may need explaining, but I don't know which details are you interested in - you haven't mentioned.

Comment: Great answer! Is there any special reason for using `alignas(T) char data[sizeof(T)];` instead of `T data;` and `ErasedNodePointer<T> next[1];` instead of `ErasedNodePointer<T> next;` in the `AlignmentExtractor` struct?

Comment: @MikhailVasilyev `offsetof` requires us to have a standard layout type, according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof). If `T` would be non-standard layout, that would make that struct non-standard layout too. As for `next[1]` vs `next`, I *think* `next` would work just as well.